# Use coo_matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I'm doing a Matrix Factorization in TensorFlow, I want to use coo_matrix from Spicy.sparse cause it uses less memory and it makes it easy to put all my data into my matrix for training data.

Is it possible to use coo_matrix to initialize a variable in tensorflow?

Or do I have to create a session and feed the data I got into tensorflow using sess.run() with feed_dict.

I hope that you understand my question and my problem otherwise comment and i will try to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest thing TensorFlow has to [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) is [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor), which is the sparse equivalent of [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor). It will probably be easiest to feed a `coo_matrix` into your program.

A `tf.SparseTensor` is a slight generalization of COO matrices, where the tensor is represented as three dense `tf.Tensor` objects:

- `indices`: An `N` x `D` matrix of `tf.int64` values in which each row represents the coordinates of a non-zero value. `N` is the number of non-zeroes, and `D` is the rank of the equivalent dense tensor (2 in the case of a matrix).
- `values`: A length-`N` vector of values, where element `i` is the value of the element whose coordinates are given on row `i` of `indices`.
- `dense_shape`: A length-`D` vector of `tf.int64`, representing the shape of the equivalent dense tensor.

For example, you could use the following code, which uses [`tf.sparse_placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_placeholder) to define a `tf.SparseTensor` that you can feed, and a [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensorValue) that represents the actual value being fed :

```
sparse_input = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[100, 100])
# ...
train_op = ...

coo_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(...)

# Wrap `coo_matrix` in the `tf.SparseTensorValue` form that TensorFlow expects.
# SciPy stores the row and column coordinates as separate vectors, so we must 
# stack and transpose them to make an indices matrix of the appropriate shape.
tf_coo_matrix = tf.SparseTensorValue(
    indices=np.array([coo_matrix.rows, coo_matrix.cols]).T,
    values=coo_matrix.data,
    dense_shape=coo_matrix.shape)
```

Once you have converted your `coo_matrix` to a `tf.SparseTensorValue`, you can feed `sparse_input` with the `tf.SparseTensorValue` directly:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={sparse_input: tf_coo_matrix})
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I wanted. But why do you do 
sparse_input = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[100, 100])

Comment: It's just an example way of creating a `tf.SparseTensor` for you to feed. You don't have to use that particular `dtype` or `shape`, and you can feed any `tf.SparseTensor` with your constructed `tf.SparseTensorValue` (as long as it has a compatible `dtype` and `shape`).

Comment: Thanks for a fast response.

Comment: mrry, you seem to have knowledge about SparseTensors. Why do i get a error when the indices aren't in order ? i dont want to order all the indices i got so i hope you can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577773/initializing-tensors Link to new question her in Stackoverflow i started