# How to read SciPy sparse matrix into Tensorflow's placeholder

Tags: tensorflow, scipy

It's possible to read dense data by this way:

```
# tf - tensorflow, np - numpy, sess - session
m = np.ones((2, 3))
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=m.shape)
sess.run(placeholder, feed_dict={placeholder: m})
```

How to read scipy sparse matrix (for example scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) into tf.placeholder or maybe tf.sparse_placeholder ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that currently TF does not have a good way to read from sparse data. If you do not want to convert a your sparse matrix into a dense one, you can try to construct a [sparse tensor.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor).

Here is what [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#sparse_input_data) tells you:

> SparseTensors don't play well with queues. If you use SparseTensors
>   you have to decode the string records using tf.parse_example after
>   batching (instead of using tf.parse_single_example before batching).

Answer (score 0):

To feed SciPy sparse matrix to TF placeholder

- Option 1: you need to use `tf.sparse_placeholder`. In [Use coo_matrix in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560245/use-coo-matrix-in-tensorflow) shows the way to feed data to a `sparse_placeholder`
- Option 2: you need to convert sparse matrix to NumPy dense matrix and feed to `tf.place_holder` (of course, this way is impossible when the converted dense matrix is out of memory)