# Followup on question "Use coo_matrix in TensorFlow"

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560245/use-coo-matrix-in-tensorflow) was mentioned:

```
tf_coo_matrix = tf.SparseTensorValue(
indices=np.array([coo_matrix.rows, coo_matrix.cols]).T,
values=coo_matrix.data,
dense_shape=coo_matrix.shape)
```

I'm trying to understand why one needs to transpose a scipy sparse matrix when using TensorFlow. Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor), `indices` is expected to be a 2-dimensional tensor with dimensions `(N, ndims)`, where `N` is the number of non-zero values in the sparse tensor and `ndims` is its number of dimensions. For a sparse matrix (two dimensions), each row will contain the row and the column of the corresponding value in `values`.

In the snippet, `coo_matrix.rows` is an array of row indices of the sparse matrix, and `coo_matrix.cols` is an array of column indices. `np.array([coo_matrix.rows, coo_matrix.cols])` will be an array with two rows and `N` columns, which is the opposite order of what a sparse tensor expects, so transposing it with `.T` you get the `(N, 2)` indices tensor. Not that you are not transposing the sparse matrix, the indices still remain the same, you are just giving them to `tf.SparseTensorValue` in the required order. You could get the same result by doing, for example, `np.stack([coo_matrix.rows, coo_matrix.cols], axis=1)`.